# R Studio not installing

Tags: r, rstudio

I am attempting to install R studio but I am getting this error:

[image: error]

I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it multiple times but I still get this error, can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags for your question. You are only going to attract downvotes and close votes.

Comment: I don't see an error...this is just a dialog asking you to show where R is installed. R and RStudio aren't the same thing—RStudio the IDE requires R the language to be installed

Comment: If the question is just how to install RStudio, going to the RStudio [download page](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download) tells you there are 2 steps. The first is to install R. If you're having trouble installing a piece of software such as this, I'd recommend you first read its installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that in order for it to install it needs R installed are you computer also. [Install R](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html) onto your computer and this "error" should go away.